Show that $\tau_{s}(a)=as$ is a representation.
Let $G \le GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ a finite group of invertible matrices $n \times n$, and let $V=M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be the space of matrices $n \times n$. Let $s \in G$, show that $\tau_{s}(a)=as$ is a representation of $G$ in $V$, for all $a \in V$.
For $\tau$ to be a representation, $\tau$ has to be a group homomorphism, which takes $G$ in $GL(V)$. I'm having difficulty proving that $\tau$ is in fact a homomorphism. I know that $\tau_{st}(a) = (\tau_{s} \circ \tau_{t})(a) = \tau_{s}(\tau_{t}(a)) = \tau_{s}(at) = ats = \tau_{ts}(a)$, but $ats \neq ast$ and by the property of group homomorphisms, we must have to $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$, if $\varphi$ is any homomorphism. What do I do?

Writing $\tau_s(a) \circ \tau_t(a)$ doesn't make any sense.  I think you mean to start $(\tau_s \circ \tau_t)(a) = \tau_s(\tau_t(a)) = \ldots$

What you have is a version of the right regular representation, which represents the opposite group of $G$, not $G$ itself.  The reason is exactly what you've noticed.  [My remark assumes you compose functions right-to-left, not left-to-right.]  To get a repn of $G$ this way, you should map $a \mapsto as^{-1}$.

In other words, if you've transcribed the problem correctly, I maintain it's wrong.

You ran into a snag here because it's not a homomorphism.
One has the left regular representation (for any $G$) $\lambda $ given by the group acting on itself by left translation.   And there's the right regular representation $\rho$ given by right translation by the inverse (the inverse makes it a homomorphism):  $\rho_s(g)=gs^{-1}.$
Either one can be used in the proof of Cayley's theorem (that a group $G$ can be embedded in $\mathscr S_{\mid G\mid}.)$
As @Randall points out, the $\tau _s$ you defined is a homomorphism (and thus you get a representation)  on the opposite group $G^{\text {op}}.$  But not on $G.$
$G^{\text {op}} $ is the group with the same underlying set as $G,$ but with group operation $*'$ given by $g*'h\equiv h*g,$ where $*$ is the operation on $G.$
